# Can i retrieve data from the database while in a TransactionScope?

Tags: database, transactionscope

I have a TransactionScope that houses another TransactionScope which makes an insert, then i commit the inner TransactionScope. Before i commit the outer TransactionScope, i want to be able to retrieve the data of my insert from the database. Is it possible to do that?

Visual Aid:

```
TransactionScope #1
  TransactionScope #2
    //Insert
  TransactionScope #2 -- Committed

  //Can i retrieve the values of my insert from the database from here?
TransactionScope #1 -- Committed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do that as long as you're doing it from within the same transaction.

Comment: I would add that if you wan your inner Transaction to be roll-overed independantly from its outer transaction your can create it with the TransactionScope.RequiresNew option. But beware of the deadlocks then...